# relational type operation on key value storage

Tags: mysql, redis, key-value, relational

in my objects table i have

```
id | type | parent | order | created
```

and then in my data table i have

```
object_id | key | value
```

i want to get object of type 'x' where key 'y' === 'z' in the most optimal way possible.

ie. get user where slug === 'jonny'

i'm currently doing it with joins, because i'm doing this in mysql as a quick test. but i'll be moving to redis or a similar key/value storage system so obviously that won't work.

Comment: If your data model is relational, why don't you stay with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot adapt or convert a relational model to a key-value store: you need to rethink your data model in term or structure, and in term of access path.

In your example, with redis, I would use:

- one hash per object containing both static (type,parent,order,created) and dynamic (the ones you stored in the data table) properties
- one set per type of objects to index the object types
- one set per property value you need to search on

With a schema-less key-value store, there is no need to separate static and dynamic properties like you did with MySQL.

Searches can be done by intersecting the sets. The sets have to be maintained manually (i.e. each time you add/delete an object, you need to update the corresponding sets).

Once you have the result of a search, corresponding object properties can be retrieved by pipelining several hgetall commands, or by using the sort command.

**Example:**

```
# Add 3 objects and their properties
hmset obj:1 type user parent nil order 1 created 20120901 key_slug jonny key_tag dummy key_author Bob
hmset obj:2 type user parent nil order 2 created 20120901 key_slug jonny key_tag not_dummy key_author Dan
hmset obj:3 type admin parent nil order 3 created 20120901

# Add type index
sadd type:user 1 2
sadd type:admin 3

# Add dynamic properties indexes
sadd key_slug:jonny 1 2
sadd key_tag:dummy 1
sadd key_tag:not_dummy 2
sadd key_author:Bob 1
sadd key_author:Dan 2

# Find objects whose type is user, author is Bob and slug is jonny
sinter type:user key_author:Bob key_slug:jonny

# Find properties of object 1
hgetall obj:1
```